# How to parse a float with nightly Rust?

Tags: rust

I can't find out how to parse a float from current Rust, [according to the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/primitive.f32.html#method.from_str) I think this should work :

```
use std::f32;
use std::from_str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let result = f32::from_str("3.14");
    println!("{}", result.unwrap());
}
```

but the compiler complains :

```
<anon>:5:18: 5:31 error: unresolved name `f32::from_str`.
<anon>:5     let result = f32::from_str("3.14");
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(See on Rust playpen : [here](http://is.gd/XjLSpB))

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, static trait methods can only be called via the trait, with the return value deduced via type inference, so `let x: Option<f32> = FromStr::from_str("3.14");`. This will be made more flexible when [UFCS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/96fe95c27bed1cef52e9795fbd4c6ce20cbfa476/active/0046-ufcs.md) is implemented ([#16293](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16293)), at least removing the need to write the full `Option<f32>` type signature.

However, in this specific case, the recommended approach is the freestanding [`from_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/from_str/fn.from_str.html) function which is in the prelude, and so can be used with no imports. The function works with an explicit type annotation on the variable binding like the above, but can also just use a shorter type hint:

```
fn main() {
    let result = from_str::<f32>("3.14");
    println!("{}", result.unwrap());
}
```

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20from_str%3A%3A%3Cf32%3E%28%223.14%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20result.unwrap%28%29%29%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Actually this solution is broken because we receive the error `error: unresolved name \`from_str\``.

Comment: @DavideAversa You may use `"3.14".parse::<f32>()` instead.

Answer (score 10):

In *1.0.0 alpha~Nightly* you can use [std::str::StrExt::parse](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.parse) instead

```
assert_eq!("3.14".parse(), Ok(3.14f64))
```

Also here's a sample with your code

```
fn main() {
    let result: f32 = "3.14".parse().unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

[Playpen link](http://is.gd/rNpA2P)

Comment: Each of your examples also has an alternative form that allows you to not use the (in my opinion) ugly `::<type>` syntax: `let result: Option<f32> = "3.14".parse()` and `assert_eq!("3.14".parse(), Some(3.14f64))`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I've udpated the code, thanks so much :)